# Inserir documentos no MongoDB via pymongo

Tags: python

Boa noite. Estou usando o python pela primeira vez a fim de rodar um crawler. Consegui rodar e pegar as aquisições e quero salva-las no MongoDB via pymongo. Tentei seguir a documentação oficial mas por algum motivo não estou conseguindo. Alguém sabe como inserir ou já fez algo parecido? Abraços.

```
import scrapy
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient


class NameSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'SpiderName'
    allowed_domains = ['randomDomain']
    start_urls = ['randomDomain Url']

    def parse(self, response):
        data = []
        for selector in response.css("span.style_data"):
            data.append(selector.css("::text").extract()

        print(data)

# O data aparece como desejado,agora desejo salvar seu conteudo no MongoDB.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, estão faltando informações sobre o seu problema, mas vou tentar ajudar da melhor forma possível.

Primeiramente seria interessante se você já entendesse os conceitos de um banco não relacional. No MongoDB temos basicamente temos: **coleções** e **documentos**, e em resumo:

- **coleções:** grupo de documentos armazenados (em comparação bem genérica seria similar a tabela em um banco de dados relacional),
- **documentos:** forma de armazenar os dados propriamente dito, no MongoDB os documentos são armazenados no formato **JSON** (no caso do `pymongo` são utilizados `dicionários` para representar **documentos**).

Operações básicas do `pymongo`:

- Criar um *client* para conexão e conectar a um bd:

  `from pymongo import MongoClient`

  `client = MongoClient()`

  `#conectar a um bd local`

  `client = MongoClient('localhost', 8000)` ou
  `client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:8000')`
- Acessar a um banco de dados:

  `banco = client.crawler_db` ou
  `banco = client['crawler_db']`
- Acessar a uma coleção em específico:

  `colecao = banco.dados_crawler` ou `colecao = banco['dados_crawler']`

  *obs: coleções e bancos são criados a partir do momento em que é inserido o primeiro documento!*
- Manipulando documentos:

  `doc_exemplo = {
    "dado1" : 123,
    "dado2" : "teste_bd"
  }`

Esse é o formato esperado de um documento do MongoDB (formato JSON).

- Inserindo um documento:

  `dados_crawler = banco.dados_crawler`

  `resultado = dados_crawler.insert_one(doc_exemplo)`
- Inserindo vários documentos:

  `resultado = dados_crawler.insertMany([doc_exemplo, doc_exemplo2])`

Para não me estender mais, acredito que isso seja suficiente para resolver seu problema.

Seguem referências de documentação/tutoriais com exemplos:

1. [Tutorial Básico - *inglês*](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/tutorial.html)
2. [Introdução ao MongoDB - inglês](https://realpython.com/introduction-to-mongodb-and-python/)

Comment: Muito obrigado! Eu escrevi com poucas informações porque não conheço muito de python e MongoDB (e nem de progamação em geral) mas com seu post consegui entender mais sobre banco de dados e consegui fazer o que eu queria. Abraços